# Why do I get the cannot read property of undefined when adding a second item to the checkoutList?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm making a checkoutList for some kind of webshop, and I'm trying to make a function that makes the quantity 1 higher, when the same element is pressed twice. The first item does add to the checkoutList, but whenever a second item is added an error "cannot read property '0' of undefined" is showing in console.

```
export class CheckoutComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() checkoutItem: any

  checkoutItems = [
    // {name: "Test1", amount: 4, price: 100  },
    // {name: "test2", amount: 2, price: 20  },
    // {name: "test3", amount: 6, price: 50  },
    // {name: "test4", amount: 1, price: 8  },
  ];

  checkoutTotal = 0;

  constructor(productservice: ProductService, private msg: MessengerService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.msg.getMsg().subscribe((product: Product) => {
     this.addProductToCheckoutList(product)
    })
  }

  addProductToCheckoutList(product: Product){

  let productExists = false;

  for(let i in this.checkoutItems){
     if(this.checkoutItems[i].id == product.id){
        this.checkoutItem[i].quantity++
        productExists = true
        break;
    }
  }

  if(!productExists){
    this.checkoutItems.push({
       id: product.id,
       name: product.name,
       quantity: 1,
       price: product.price
    })
  }
  
      this.checkoutTotal = 0 
      this.checkoutItems.forEach(item => {
        this.checkoutTotal += (item.quantity * item.price)
      })
  }
}
```

I've added an image, to clearify what the page looks like, and what the error looks like.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can resolve it by changing

`this.checkoutItem[i].quantity++;`

to

`this.checkoutItems[i].quantity++;`